# How to verify/compare 2 values in Selenium?

Tags: java, string, selenium, hashmap, webdriver

1. I have an input file which contains some String values. Lets Say String one.
2. On a web page, I am identifying a web element and getting its value as a String. lets say String two.

```
    String one = "abc" //Value from input file.
    String two = "USabc" // Value from identifying a web element.
```

I have to compare these 2 strings and my test case is that String two should contain "US" as well as contents of String one which are "abc"

How can i do this ?

Also, if I have multiple inputs and multiple outputs in one script, whats the best way of doing this?

Comment: It sounds like you should use the .contains() method. `If(two.contains(one) && two.contains("US){}`

Comment: You can define function where you can pass two variables.One as input string and Other as xpath string and inside function block you can writedown the code for element and then compare with above resolution.If you could provide more info OP can provide you best possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

To compare the presence of the text within the variable **one** as well as the text **US** within the variable **two** you can use the following solution:

```
if(two.contains(one) && two.contains("US"))
    System.out.println("Comparision successful");
else
    System.out.println("Comparision unsuccessful");
```

Answer (score 0):

Selenium Assertions are the best way you can use `Assert` to compare two values.

Assertions verify that the state of the application is same to what we are expecting. Selenium Assertions can be of three types: “assert”, “verify”, and ” waitFor”. When an “assert” fails, the test is aborted. When a “verify” fails, the test will continue execution, logging the failure.
Available in

```
import org.testng.Assert;
```

and perform

```
Assert.assertEquals("one","two");
```

If you do not want your test to fail at a particular assertion and want to continue till the end and then assert, you can use `SoftAsserts`

You can read more about that here https://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/soft-asserts-in-testng-example